# How to use the LiveData value in another method of Activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, mvvm, android-livedata

I am using *MVVM* architecture and having a hard time figuring out where to store value observed from *LiveData* which just needs to be used in if statement in `onActivityResult()` of the same `Activity` or any other method.

Suppose, I've this method that observes live data from the `viewModel` in the `Activity`.

```
fun subscribeObservers() {
    myViewModel.liveData.observe(viewLifeCycleOwner, Observer { myLiveDataString ->
        setTextField(myLiveDataString)
    });
}
```

And I want to use that particular value observed from *LiveData* in `onActivityResult` of the same `Activity`.

Suppose like this,

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        if (requestCode == RC) {
            if (myLiveDataString == "ERROR") {
                showErrorDialogToUser()
            }
        }
    }
```

So my question is where should I store the data observed from *LiveData* to check for `If` statement? Should I just store it in an `Activity`? Is it a good idea?

Comment: You can use  SharedPreference or [Room Database](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room)

Comment: @Sniffer This value is already coming from database.

Comment: Just use `myViewModel.liveData.value` to get the value.

Comment: @Onik Shouldn't liveData value be retrieved only through observer method?

Comment: Not only. When observing you get notified when it changes. Nothing prevents you to check the value. LiveData is just a data holder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `myViewModel.liveData.value` to get the value.

> Shouldn't liveData value be retrieved only through observer method?

Not only. When observing, you get notified when the value changes. Nothing prevents you from checking the value. LiveData is just a data holder.

Answer (score 0):

If you just mean you want to use the `LiveData` value within the same `Activity` then create a `private String liveDataReturnValue` in your `Activity` class and assign the returned `LiveData` value from the `Observer`

```
var liveDataReturnedValue : String = "";

fun subscribeObservers() {
    myViewModel.liveData.observe(viewLifeCycleOwner, Observer { myLiveDataString ->
        setTextField(myLiveDataString);
        this@YourActivityClass.liveDataReturnedValue = myLiveDataString;
    });
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if (requestCode == RC) {
        if (myLiveDataString == "ERROR") {
            showErrorDialogToUser()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My bad. I tried my best to clear the question. But I DO NOT want the value in another activity. I just want to use the value observed in some another method of same activity.

Comment: yes in that case the code is in the second part of the answer